# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageButton

Tags: android, kotlin

So I'm fairly new to Kotlin.

I am trying to create an onClickListener on an image button to open the share interface, so that the particular video from the recyclerView can be shared via SMS, etc.

I followed various tutorials on how to do this as I am trying to execute this within a fragment, and the app just keeps crashing when I try to open the fragment in question.

I get the following error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageButton
```

Here is what my fragment code looks like:

**SearchFragment.kt**

```
class SearchFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener
{

    private var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null
    private var adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<ClipAdapter.ViewHolder>? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View
    {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false)
        loadData()
        return rootView
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        val shareBtn = view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.button_to_share)
        shareBtn.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    private fun loadData()
    {
        val service = TwitchServiceBuilder.buildService(TwitchService::class.java)
        val requestCall = service.getClips("anerdfails")

        requestCall.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Clip>>
        {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<Clip>>,
                response: Response<List<Clip>>
            )
            {
                if (response.isSuccessful)
                {
                    //process data
                    recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 2)
                    recyclerView.adapter = ClipAdapter(response.body()!!)
                } else
                {
                    //output alert
                    AlertDialog.Builder(activity!!)
                        .setTitle("API error")
                        .setMessage("Response, but something went wrong ${response.message()}")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok) { _, _ -> }
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show()
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Clip>>, t: Throwable)
            {
                //process failure
                AlertDialog.Builder(activity!!)
                    .setTitle("API error")
                    .setMessage("No response, and something went wrong $t")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok) { _, _ -> }
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show()
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?)
    {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Its toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}
```

And here are my 2 layouts for the RecyclerView:

**fragment_search.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingStart="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:paddingEnd="15dp"
    tools:context=".ui.search.SearchFragment">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:background="@drawable/search_bar"
        android:id="@+id/clipSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/clipSearch" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**clip_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".ui.search.SearchFragment">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoClip"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,2:3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/videoClip"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtChannel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtTitle"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtGame"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtChannel"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViews"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtGame"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViews">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/favouriteButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_favorite_border_24" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_to_share"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_share_24" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Seems like a simple mistake on my part, but I'm pulling my hair out trying to work out what I've done wrong to cause the error on loading.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're trying to find the button "ShareBtn" inside the fragment which is totally wrong.
the "ShareBtn" doesn't belong to the fragment, it belongs to the viewHolder which you have created inside "ClipAdapter"
What you need to do is creating an interface inside "ClipAdapter" and create an object from it inside the Adapter
then call the method which is should the clickListener delegates the click to it
lastly, you should implement it inside the fragment and put whatever logic you want
[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ai9rSGcDhyQ) link will help you implement it

Comment: Absolute legend, added the onClickListener to the `ViewHolder` class in my Adapter and the toast message is coming up as intended.

Comment: I'm glad that i helped you, Your comment made my day

Answer (score 1):

You are casting ID of view which is an `Integer` to `ImageButton` which is a `View` in this line

```
val shareBtn = R.id.button_to_share as ImageButton
```

You should use this instead

```
val shareBtn = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.button_to_share)
```

**UPDATE**

Also you should find views after fragment view got created. It means you should call `findViewById` inside `onViewCreated` and not inside `onCreateView`. If you try to find views before view of fragment gets created then you get `NullPointerException` since there is no view yet.

Comment: Brill, so that fixed the initial error I was getting. I am now getting an new error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference` - a brief Google suggested this could be due to the fact it's in the inner layout file, instead of the one which is being invoked on the `onCreateView()` method. How would I go about resolving it? I've updated the question with the layout code too.

Comment: @E.Fitzpatrick I have updated my answer. See if it solves your issue or not :D

Comment: I tried what you suggested and moved the click listener onto the `onViewCreated()` function (see original question for updated code), and I'm still getting the same error. Logcat specified that the error is from this line: `shareBtn.setOnClickListener(this)`